# How do I add a bump map to a single face on the default cube?

Tags: materials, bump

In terms suitable for an absolute beginner with no plugins or node editing, how wold you take the default starting cube, select a single face, and then add a bump map to that face alone?

This must be the simplest possible answer with no additional steps, and only for the default cube. No other object.

Just a single bump to a single face on the starting cube.

Comment: It's a significantly more complicated answer.

Comment: Please reverse the close, the other question is far more complicated and the answer is far more difficult for a beginner to follow. It includes steps that are completely unnecessary to answer this question.

Answer (score 6):

create a second material in your slot and select it.

[image]

go in edit mode, select top face:

[image]

click on "assign"

[image]

[image]